# How Can I Remove Cached Artifact from Local WebSphere?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, websphere, ear, artifact

I've created a local WebSphere configuration in Intellij Idea.

Previously, this configuration had a .ear artifact that I've since removed from deployment in the IntelliJ 'application servers' tab. However, whenever I attempt to start up the server, it still attempts to launch that artifact despite that I've removed the artifact and module from the IntelliJ project.

The issue is that the cached artifact fails to build, so the server can't be started up... so I can't boot the local server to remove the artifact because it automatically attempts to build and crashes despite not being on my IntelliJ deploy list.

Is there a way to remove the artifact (or at least remove it from the deployment list) by manipulating the files in the local WebSphere directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `<application …` tags from the `server.xml` file.

```
WS_HOME\usr\servers\defaultServer\server.xml
```